# Simple plugin not working

Tags: jquery

Good Day,

I'm trying to write this simple plugin to highlight a table row when you click on the cell:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.rowHighlighter = function (options) {

        // Establish our default settings
        options = $.extend({
            text: 'Hello, World!',
            color: null,
            fontStyle: null,
            tableClass: null,   // tableClass = '.cardNumbers', columnValue = 'cardNo'
            columnValue: null,
            rows: null
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            console.log('Inside rowHighlighter plugin...');

            $(this).on('click', '#excelTable tr', function (e) {
                $('#excelTable tr').removeClass('highlighted-cell');
                $(this).addClass('highlighted-cell');
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The code itself works when it's outside of the plugin.  I've verified that the css is valid.

I have a table that gets generated but the main table tag:

```
<table id="excelTable">
</table>
```

I register the plugin with the table:

```
$(function() {
    $('#excelTable').rowHighlighter();
});
```

Comment: Please be specific when asking questions.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Your HTML doesn't have tr's referenced in your plugin. And why are you even invoking the plugin on a selector if the plugin has the ID of the table hard coded? This does something, if you want to try to adapt it to whatever your end goal is. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWbxqe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is just highlight clicked tr, try this :

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.rowHighlighter = function (options) {

        // Establish our default settings
        options = $.extend({
            text: 'Hello, World!',
            color: null,
            fontStyle: null,
            tableClass: null,   // tableClass = '.cardNumbers', columnValue = 'cardNo'
            columnValue: null,
            rows: null
        }, options);

        return $(this).each(function (i,table) {

            var trs = $(table).find('tr');

            $(trs).on('click',function(){
                $(trs).removeClass('highlighted-cell');
                $(this).addClass('highlighted-cell');
            });

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/knc61tvL/)

Comment: You need to wrap `this` in `$(this)`, it's already a jQuery instance

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be *"you **don't** need to wrap `this`..."*

Comment: @Phil Yep, I know.